# Strange behaviour in Grails' Integration Tests

Tags: grails, integration-testing, missingmethodexception

I am doing Grails tutorials on IBM[(here)](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-grails11188/index.html) but I am a quite disappointed by an integration test.
To sum up : I call a method who render a JSON object according to the ID (iata).

My domain is :

```
 class Airport {        
    String name
    String iata
}
```

My controller is :

```
class AirportController {

    // In order to enable scaffolding
    def scaffold = Airport

    def iata = {
        def iata = params.id?.toUpperCase() ?: "NO IATA"
        def airport = Airport.findByIata(iata)
        if (!airport) {
            airport = new Airport(iata: iata, name: "Not found")
        }

        render airport as JSON
    }    
}
```

When I do : 
`http://localhost:8080/trip-planner/airport/iata/foo` (in order to retreive null value) or
`http://localhost:8080/trip-planner/airport/iata/DEN` (for DENVER), the method works fine !

The issue is my Integration tests :

```
class AirportControllerTests extends GroovyTestCase {
    void testWithGoodIata(){
        def controller = new AirportController()
        controller.metaClass.getParams = { ->
        return ["id":"den"]
        }

        controller.iata()

        def response = controller.response.contentAsString
        assertTrue response.contains("Denver")
    }

    void testWithWrongIata() {
        def controller = new AirportController()
        controller.metaClass.getParams = { ->
        return ["id":"foo"]
        }

        controller.iata()

        def response = controller.response.contentAsString
        assertTrue response.contains("\"name\":\"Not found\"")      
    }
}
```

The problem is:

Whenever I run the tests (by running : `grails test-app -integration trip.planner.AirportControllerTests`), I will always obtain a good behavior in the first test and a `groovy.lang.MissingMethodException` in the **second** test. (even if I switch the two : the second test always fail)

If I run them separately , it works.
The exception occurred at this line (in the controller) : `def airport = Airport.findByIata(iata)`

Is that someting to do with "transactional" ? Any help would be great :)

P.S : I am using Grails 2.2.1

The exception stacktrace :

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: trip.planner.Airport.methodMissing() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
    at trip.planner.AirportController$_closure4.doCall(AirportController.groovy:39)
    at trip.planner.AirportControllerTests.testWithWrongIata(AirportControllerTests.groovy:25)
```

Comment: A couple questions that can possibly improve your code (and maybe help solve the problem): why the logic to query the database is inside the controller? Without business logic, you should be able to test the controller behaviour in a unit test, which only has the responsibility to handle request and response. Second, don't use a fake id to find the airport, simply use null instead of 'NO IATA'.

Comment: Why the logic is inside the controller ? The controller have to do the logic, that's why it's here (I am just doing a tutorial from IBM). I replace "NO IATA" by null, but it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't explained myself well. The logic is required of course, but it should live inside a service, not a controller.

Comment: Yeah right, so you think I have to create a service (that my controller call) ? It's just improvement, I don't look for this (it's a tutorial ...), I don't think it's gonna solve my problem, it will just shift it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the metaclass changes you're making in one test are somehow leaking through to the other.  But you don't need to (and shouldn't) manipulate the metaclass in an *integration* test, just say

```
def controller = new AirportController()
controller.params.id = "den"
```

You only need to do mocking for *unit* tests.

Bear in mind that the tutorial you're looking at was written way back in 2008 (in the Grails 1.0.x days), and Grails has moved on a very long way since then, with some components (including testing) having been through one or more complete rewrites.

Comment: Thanks, I might have to find another tutorial... I made the changes you said in order to not manipulate the MetaClass but unfortunately it doesn't change anything.

Comment: @GuillaumeM can you edit the question to include the full details (and stack trace) of the `MissingMethodException`?  Which method is apparently missing and who is trying to call it?

Comment: Done. It's very strange, because i'm calling exactly the same method on both tests.

Comment: @GuillaumeM that's very odd, the only time I've seen inexplicable MMEs like that turned out to be when I didn't have the hibernate plugin installed in my application, and there it was failing consistently rather than only on the second call.  You may find more information in the unfiltered stack trace (in `stacktrace.log`) which includes more of the Groovy-internal stack frames.  But mostly yes, I'd say look for a more up to date tutorial that was written for Grails 2.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I'll search in extra logs for more details but I think I will look for another tutorial :)

Comment: I find the unfiltered stack trace. I am afraid that I will not copy/paste it here because it takes 401 lines !